# CSS to open side panel doesn't work in Angular component

Tags: css, angular

I have a simple Angular app with two components, a header and a side panel. There is a menu icon in the header, which when clicked shows the side panel.

It works when the code is in AppComponent. But it does not work, if I make the side panel into its own Angular component (SidenavComponent). I am using "transform: translateX" to hide and show the panel.

Here is a [stackblitz workplace](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsuvxz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) where the code for the panel is in AppComponent and is working.

Here is a [another stackblitz workplace](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gte11m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav%2Fsidenav.component.ts) where the code for the panel is in SideanavComponent and is NOT working.

When the menu icon is clicked, the header component sends a message to the component to open the panel. This is AppComponent in the working code and  SidenavComponent in the non-working code. The component receiving the message then applies the CSS class to open the panel.

When I run this in Chrome and open the developer tools,  the same CSS gets applied to both the working and non-working sidenav html. So I am baffled.

This was originally part of a bigger app. I removed all code unrelated to the problem that I am having and then moved it to the Stackblitz workplace.

NOTE: Both the working and non-working code has a console error when run in stackblitz: "Unhandled Promise rejection". This does not happen when run in Chrome and does not stop the working code from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that you've created a new Angular component that you want to have act the same as the `<aside>` element you had running in the AppComponent html page, right?

But then in your sidenav component, you go ahead and put a new `<aside>` element with the sidenav class *within* your new component. Do you see the problem here? You've now got an element (the component element), with its own css rules, sitting between the parent element and the sidenav element.

To resolve this, what you want is to treat your sidenav component as the element itself! This means you need a couple of changes.

Learn about applying css to the component itself (here's the trick: it's called :host in the scss file).

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

And for dynamically changing the component's classes, use @HostBinding

https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding

With these two techniques, you can remove the `<aside>` element from within your sidenav component, and the component itself will act in the way you desire.

I forked your stackblitz workplace with a working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gl3cu?file=src/app/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I erroneously left 'class="sidenav"' on the gm-sidenav element in app.component.html.  My intention is to use only what is in SidenavComponent including its SCSS. I updated my stackblitz workplace. (sorry about that)

Comment: In other words, I want to move all code related to sidenav into SidenavComponent.

Comment: Did you see my forked stackblitz? That's exactly what I did – the necessary change was to apply the css to the component itself using hostbinding. Look at the stackblitz and you'll see that it's working.

Comment: Yes I checked out your stackblitz and I appreciate the tips you taught me. But your solution uses the copy of the scss code that still remains in app.component.scss. And this is because of my mistake. I should have removed 'class="sidenav"' from the gm-sidenav element. If the code in app.component.scss and that in app.component.ts related to sidenav is deleted, it should still work. The goal is to move this code from AppComponent to SidenavComponent. I should have created two Stackblitz, one with the code in AppComponent and the other in SidenavComponent. I think i will do just that.

Comment: Oops, I had forgotten to delete the scss on the app itself, and indeed the stackblitz I'd made wouldn't work otherwise, because the definition of `sidenav--active` would not apply to host component. To fix that I simply had to add `:host.sidenav--active` in the component definition. Check out the stackblitz now and you'll see it works, without scss in the `app.component.scss`

Comment: Terrific! Thanks a lot. I am not quite sure why the css has to be applied to the host element, but I am very glad to have a solution. I read your above reasoning, but I think that was based on having css code in AppComponent also.

Comment: It has to be applied to the host element because in Angular the scss code in a component definition only applies to child elements of the component. Any scss intended for the host itself needs to have the `:host` notation, or be defined in a parent scope of the component.

Comment: I never realized that. That explains a lot. Thanks again.